# PHP Echo File List - List Fed From Multiple Subdirectories

Tags: php, html, list, file-upload, recursion

I am attempting to list the set of files stored in all subdirectories within member's unique folder.

Here you can see how the style in which files are being saved:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $udir = "members/".$id."/";
    $date = date("Y.m.d");
    $curdir = $udir.$date."/";
    $datetime = date("Y.m.d.G.i.s");
    $fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $extn = pathinfo($fname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!is_dir($curdir)){
        mkdir($udir.$date, 0700);
    }
    $ufile = $curdir.$datetime.".".$extn;
    $allexts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($ext, $allexts)){
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $ufile)) {
            echo "File upload was successful.";
        } else {
            echo "An error has occured. Please try again.";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid file. Please try again.";
    }
```

Now, I am trying to draw upon those files as shown here:

```
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $udir = "members/".$id."/";
    if ($dir = opendir("$udir")) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
```

Which, as you may have guessed, only returns a list of the subdirectories within the member's unique id folder. Thus, I moved on to play with recursive functions, which seem to dig through the directories, but I can't figure out how to merge the two. The below code returns the full paths of all files, but that is as far as I've gotten.

```
    $path = realpath("$udir");
    $recur = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
    foreach($recur as $files => $recur){
    echo "$files";}
```

Any guidance in merging these two functions or a complete alternative would be most appreciated!

**EDIT: I've gone on to try utilizing a suggestion below, however I am not getting a result when calling upon $list. Here is the modified code.**

```
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $udir = "members/".$id."/";
    if ($dir = opendir($udir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (is_dir($file) === true){
                    $dir = opendir("$file");
                    $file = readdir($dir);
                    $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                    closedir($file);
                }
                else if (is_file($file) === true){
                $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
```

Comment: Some points about your code: You don't check if the upload actually succeeded; you're trusting the user to not lie about the file type; and you're using timestamps with a 1-second granularity for filenames, with no provision for collisions if two files finish uploading at the same timestamp; and use you path_info to get the original file extension properly, and then promptly throw it away for a highly inefficient explode/end operation set.

Comment: @MarcB thank you for the criticism without suggestion. +1 for educating the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. Why don't you just move the second block to a function and call it recursively?

```php
function listDir($udir) {
    $list = '';
    if ($dir = opendir($udir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                if (is_dir($udir.'\\'.$file) === true) {
                    $list .= listDir($udir.'\\'.$file);
                } else if (is_file($udir.'\\'.$file) === true) {
                    $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.'\\'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    return $list;
}

echo '<ul>'.listDir('D:\<test>\<test>').'</ul>';
```

**EDIT:** updated code to include feedback

Comment: when i try to implement your suggestion, it tries to open the files themselves as directories and spits an error for each contained file.

Comment: Here is what i've done as an extension of what you've written, however it doesn't print anything when i echo $list. `$id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $udir = "members/".$id."/";
if ($dir = opendir($udir)) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {   if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
   if (is_dir($file) === true){
    $dir = opendir("$file");
    $file = readdir($dir);
    $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    closedir($file);    }
   else if (is_file($file) === true){
   $list .= '<li><a href="'.$udir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
   }
  }
 }
 closedir($dir);
}`

Comment: I just created a little page to test the script. You are right, it was not working. I therefor updated the code and it is now working, however the links don't work in my environment because i cannot load local files... But I think i can leave the details to you.

Comment: there is still no output data set. not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: thats what we always say, but it works with me...
where what disconnect is? - try echoing $file within the first if block, then within the why block and so on. where does it stop working?

Comment: i'm listing as answered for your consistent feedback and help. i'm sure i'll figure out what the issue is on my end. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way

```
function getDirectory($path = '.', $level = 0)
{
    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' ); 
    $dh = @opendir( $path );      
    while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) )
    {      
        if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) )
        {             
            $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) );
            if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) )
            {             
                echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
                getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) );

            }
            else
            {             
                echo "$spaces $file<br />";            
            }
        } 
    } 
    closedir( $dh ); 
} 

getDirectory("/var");
```